# Scaffold-DbContext not generating virtual navigation properties (EF Core 2.1)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-2.1

I am using EF Core 2.1 database-first.
I use `Scaffold-DbContext` to create/update my models (the .cs files)

I want to enable [lazy-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading), and I have added `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` in my Startup.cs

Now, how do I get `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate virtual navigation properties?

Comment: You could use EF Core Power Tools with Handlebars templates to enable this

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ. Finally found an instruction here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering