# Entity framework core 2.2 not generating virtual properties for lazyloading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to generate context and classes from an existing `SQL server` database.

I've installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`.

In the Context there are virtual `DbSet` for all my columns, example:

`public virtual DbSet<Device> Device { get; set; }`

However no virtual properties for my **many-to-many relations** are added to the column classes. When i try to use `Include` i can only access the `xref-table` class.

How do i get ef core to generate virtual properties in the column classes?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827976/scaffold-dbcontext-not-generating-virtual-navigation-properties-ef-core-2-1 . The scaffolder is meant for simple tasks and lazy loading is something people want to *avoid*. If you don't want to load a related entity, don't even add it as a property. Complex applications have *multiple* contexts, according to their use cases

Comment: ErikEJ's tool offers more options than the simple EF Core scaffolder, including the ability to enable lazy loading